# How to select or deselect a row in a Table using Data Grid Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

How to select and deselect a row using onclick in @mui/x-data-grid with out the checkboxSelection prop,
I am trying to implement selection or deselection of a row in Mui
Below is Table Component file

```
import * as React from "react";
import { v1 } from "uuid";
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarExport
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";

//css
import css from "./index.module.css";

export default function Table(props) {
  const { tableHeader, data } = props;


  data.forEach((element) => {
    element["id"] = v1();
  });

  function CustomToolbar() {
    return (
      <GridToolbarContainer>
        <GridToolbarExport className={`${css.btn}`} />
      </GridToolbarContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 350, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        className={`${css.root}`}
        rows={data}
        columns={tableHeader}
        pageSize={10}
        rowHeight={30}
        autoPageSize={true}
        disableColumnMenu={true}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MUI docs](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/selection/), you will need to go through the `useDemoData` hook in the package `@mui/x-data-grid-generator`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';

export default function SingleRowSelectionGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid {...data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In case you would like to **unselect** a row, simply hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on it.

Comment: is there a way i can select and deselect the row without using the control button and on the onclick?

Comment: you can select without Ctrl. 
Ctrl is for unselect. Kindly follow the link to the official docs. Thank you

Comment: i know but is there a way around for it, without the ctrl key

Comment: What do you want exactly? You now have 2 different ways to achieve it. Why you want it differently?